# How to provide return types with static parameters to provided methods

Tags: f#, type-providers

F# 4.0 introduced the ability to provide static parameters to provided methods (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2014/11/12/announcing-a-preview-of-f-4-0-and-the-visual-f-tools-in-vs-2015.aspx)

I want the return type of my provided method to depend upon the static parameters the user supplies.

I need to define the return type outside of the DefineStaticParameters callback in order that I can pass it to `this.AddNamespace` but unfortunately this means that `AddMethod` gets called multiple times and I end up with a bunch of unwanted overloads.
If I move the creation of `returnType` inside the `DefineStaticParameters` callback then I cannot pass it to `AddNamespace` and the type provider no longer functions.

How do I resolve this conundrum?

Example code:

```
[<TypeProvider>]
type MyTypeProvider (config : TypeProviderConfig) as this =
    inherit TypeProviderForNamespaces ()

    let ns = "Acme"
    let asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

    let t = ProvidedTypeDefinition(asm, ns, "MyStaticClass", Some typeof<obj>, IsErased = true)    
    let returnType = ProviderImplementation.ProvidedTypes.ProvidedTypeDefinition(asm, ns, "MyReturnType", Some typeof<obj>, IsErased = true, HideObjectMethods = true)

    let myStaticMethod =
      let m = ProvidedMethod("SomeStaticMethod", [], typeof<obj>, IsStaticMethod = true)

      m.DefineStaticParameters(staticParams, fun nm args ->

        let providedMethod = ... // Generate a method for the return type depending on the args
        returnType.AddMember(providedMethod) // PROBLEM: This gets called multiple times and adds unwanted overloads to my returnType

        let m2 =
          let myParam = ProvidedParameter("foo", typeof<int>)
          ProvidedMethod(nm, [myParam], returnType, IsStaticMethod = true)

        m2.InvokeCode <- fun args3 ->
          <@@
            // invoke code goes here
          @@>

        t.AddMember(m2)
        m2
        )
      m

    do
      t.AddMember(myStaticMethod)
      this.AddNamespace(ns, [t;returnType])

[<assembly:TypeProviderAssembly>]
do ()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to add new types to the namespace each time a different static parameter is used, then I think the only way to do that would be to store the information you need in a cache and trigger the `Invalidate` event when you need to add a new type to the namespace, repopulating all of the types from your cache afterwards.

Comment: This seems like a really bad API design. I wonder if providedtypes.fs could be modified such that DefineStaticParameters returns a ProvidedTypeInfo[] instead of unit, or better yet, takes a continuation as a parameter.

Comment: The problem isn't with providedTypes.fs, it's with the low level type provider API itself, where `IProvidedNamespace`'s `GetTypes` method returns a `Type[]` and doesn't provide any way to add additional types.


But perhaps you could use a single type and then nest each individual type you generate within that container type as a member, rather than trying to make them direct children of the namespace...

Comment: The thing is the DefineStaticParameters callback gets triggered a lot (a few times when you first load a project that uses the type provider, and then at least once every time you press dot on an instance of the return type in visual studio), so I'd still presumably be generating a ton of unnecessary classes.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to add caching logic so that you don't create duplicate types unnecessarily.